# Jquery error too much recursion multiple onclick events

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am searching on Google and on stackoverflow for the error: too much recursion that i have with this script. But i don't found a solution.
I try with event.stopPropagation(); but don't work for me in this script.
URL/page where script is running: https://webdesignrebry.be/step/verloop/
I am using wordpress.
On the page you have a href link and links in submenu that switch to the divi tabs in the left side.
Can anybody help me? Thanks!

```
(function($){
    $('.voorbereiding').on('click', function(event){
        $('.ds-tab-cube .et_pb_tab_0 a').click();
    }); 
    $('.ontwikkeling').on('click', function(event){
        $('.ds-tab-cube .et_pb_tab_1 a').click();
    }); 
    $('.peiling').on('click', function(event){
        $('.ds-tab-cube .et_pb_tab_2 a').click();
    }); 
})(jQuery);

(function($){
    $('.valorisatie').on('click', function(event){
        $('.ds-tab-cube .et_pb_tab_3 a').click(); 
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You're raising click events within click events, which are caught by click event handlers which then raise more click events... Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code

```
  (jQuery);
        (function($){

        $('.voorbereiding').on('click', function(event){

     $('.et_pb_tabs_controls .et_pb_tab_0 a').click();
        }); 

        $('.ontwikkeling').on('click', function(event){

     $('.et_pb_tabs_controls .et_pb_tab_1 a').click();
        }); 

        $('.peiling').on('click', function(event){

     $('.ds-tab-cube .et_pb_tab_2 a').click();
        }); 
        })(jQuery);
        (function($){

        $('.valorisatie').on('click', function(event){
     $('.et_pb_tabs_controls .et_pb_tab_3 a').click();
     });    
    })(jQuery);
```

Use above code in this javascript file :- https://webdesignrebry.be/step/wp-content/themes/Divi-Ultimate/js/custom-js.js

Comment: If any help related to wordpress and magento you can reach me using my email jscatoz@gmail.com